# Resize xcode inspector panel to show labels

Tags: xcode

I cannot see any of the attributes no matter how much I stretch the pane. The drop down resize but not the labels. How can know what values I am setting?

[image]

Comment: It’s a well known issue and an oft repeated complaint. File a bug with Apple, use shorter Inspectable names, and move on.

Comment: I appears there is no way to solve it atm, thanks. I can make my own inspectable names shorter, but harder to do when a class is an external library

Comment: File a bug report.